# How to have multiple Regex pattern validators in angular6

Tags: angular

I am trying to add multiple regex patterns in angular6 reactive form. From one SO answer I got this

```
ceInterfacename: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'), {'number': ''})
  ]),
```

And in HTML

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput id='ceInterfacename' placeholder="CE Interface Name *"
      formControlName="ceInterfacename" [readonly]='isEditing && disableCeinterface()' />
   <mat-error
      *ngIf="peAddForm.controls.ceInterfacename.hasError('required') && (peAddForm.controls.ceInterfacename.dirty || peAddForm.controls.ceInterfacename.touched)">
      CE Interface Name is required
   </mat-error>
   <mat-error
      *ngIf="peAddForm.controls.ceInterfacename.hasError('number')">
      XYZ Interface Name is invalid
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem is that is is not showing the mat-error text **XYZ Interface Name is invalid**

But is highlighting the input as invalid.

please help

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start using ErrorStateMatcher and CustomValidators, where the regex is defined in the validators.

CUSTOM VALIDATORS EXAMPLE

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';


export class CustomValidators {

   static onlyWhitespace(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if ((control.value.trim() === '')) {
      return {onlyWhitespace: true};
    }
  }
}
```

Error state matcher can found in angular docs

https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Set the validators in the formgroup:

```
ceInterfacename: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    CustomValidators.youCusotmValidatorsName,
  ]),
```

And in html you call the validators like this

```
        <mat-error *ngIf="yourformControlname.hasError('you custom validators name')">Error text to show</mat-error>
```

Stackblitz example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2-nerwab

Comment: I will try that. Thanks

Comment: what is 'youCusotmValidatorsName' ??

Comment: @raju this is whatever is defined in `CustomValidators`, in Robert's example this would be `onlyWhitespace` but there could be more than one which you list inside `new FormControl('', [<<list validators here>>])`

Comment: Is the name of the customValidator you defined, in my example is onlyWhitespace, so i will call it in that way, the method remember is static so:

CustomValidators.onlyWhitespace()

Comment: how can I pass control, in  CustomValidators.onlyWhitespace(). I have not much idea, plz help

Comment: Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2-nerwab

Tell me if you have any other questions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'), {'number': ''})` you could use `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)`. Then of course in the template you have to check for `*ngIf="peAddForm.controls.ceInterfacename.hasError('pattern')"`.

Another approach would be to apply a custom validator (check out the documentation https://angular.io/guide/form-validation under "Custom validators").

Comment: then, how can I have multiple patterns?

Comment: For multiple patterns, you have to use a custom validator.